# Multiple Data Sets on the Same Scatter

Tags: matlab

I know this question may sound a bit easy, but I couldn't find what I wanted in the documentation. Basically, I would like to know if a function exists in matlab which allows me to plot data sets y1, y2, ..., yn against the same x-axis in the same scatter diagram.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Try `plotyy` if you want two different `y`-axes. http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/matlab/ref/plotyy.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use scatter + hold on. For example,

```
x   = rand(1,10);
y1  = rand(1,10);
y2  = rand(1,10);
y3  = rand(1,10);


figure; grid on;
hold on;
scatter(x, y1);  
scatter(x, y2);
scatter(x, y3);
```

Gives:

[image]